# Implementing Convolution Function for Gaussian Kernel in Python for PDF Estimation

Tags: nonparametric, density-function, kernel-smoothing

I am currently working on estimating a probability density function (PDF) nonparametrically using a Gaussian kernel. My goal is to determine the optimal bandwidth $h$ that minimizes the cross-validation (CV) score. To achieve this, I plan to implement a function in Python that computes the CV score for different values of $h$ and empirically find the value of $h$ that yields the minimum CV score.

The CV score is defined as follows:
$$
C V(h)=\frac{1}{n^2 h} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n K \star K\left(\frac{X_j-X_i}{h}\right)-\frac{2}{n(n-1)} \sum_i \sum_{j \neq i} K_h\left(X_i-X_j\right.
$$
where $K \star K$ denotes the convolution of $K$, and the convolution function $K \star$ $K(u)=\int K(u-v) K(v) d v$.

My main challenge is implementing the convolution function $K \star K(u)$ for the Gaussian kernel. I am looking for an analytical expression of this convolution that does not involve computing the integral directly, so it can be easily coded into my script.

Based on information I received, the analytical expression for the convolution of a Gaussian kernel is given by:
$$
G^{\prime}(u)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}(\sqrt{2} \sigma)} e^{-\frac{u^2}{2\left(2 \sigma^2\right)}}
$$

However, I was not provided with sources to verify this expression, and my own understanding of the subject is not very good.

Question: How can I analytically implement the convolution function of the Gaussian kernel for this purpose?